# codeigniter not upload jpeg image

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I'm yet to find a perfect solution where with codeigniter my visitors can upload jpeg extension of the image, my visitors won't convert anything, so is there a work around so we can all jpeg extensions, here is current code which gives error `invalid image extension` error.

`i'm not uploading whole code to save time and any confusion`

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'upload/path/folder';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '262144';
$config['file_name'] = 'file_name';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$this->load->library('upload',$config);
```

previously i had just `$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png`

but after complaints i added `$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png'`

but it is not working at all.

Comment: Ok have you checked your uploaded image extension ?

Comment: Check out the uploaded image mime type.

Comment: @AnkiiGangrade can you help how to do that?

Comment: Try to print `$this->upload->data()` and check `file_type:The file's Mime type`.

Comment: @AsimShahzad it is not uploading at all, works find with jpg and png but not with jpeg

Comment: @runningmark Please check my answer below,may be that will be useful to you

Comment: @AnkiiGangrade `[file_type] => image/jpeg`

Comment: @runningmark : Please check whether this mime type is there in application/config/mimes.php.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me in codeigniter 3.

**N/B: Works for the .jfif extension images**

Open your config file mimes.php and add this line

```
'jfif'  =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
```

Then in your upload configuration, use this configuration for allowed types

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|JPG|GIF|PNG|jpeg|JPEG|jfif|JFIF';
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not tested, but you can try this:

```
public function do_upload(){
    $config = array(
    'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
    'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|docx",
    'overwrite' => TRUE,
    'max_size' => "2048000", //File Size
    'max_height' => "768",
    'max_width' => "1024"
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if($this->upload->do_upload())
    {
       $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
       $this->load->view('upload_success',$data);
    }
    else
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('file_view', $error);
    }
}
```